# Image view hide navigation bar in scroll view

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

In my ipad app, there is one navigation bar and one image view within scroll view.
When i run my app, the image view hide the navigation bar.
So, i remove image view and run again, then i see navigation bar.
But, i can't click the button in navigation bar.
Please, tell me how can i solve it?

Comment: how do you add your views?? by code or XIB, if code then show us plz,,

Comment: ScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)];
    ScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

Comment: ImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0,self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

Comment: I think there is some problem in size.view.frame.size.height.

Comment: it seems the UIScrollView is on top of your navigationBar,, and if its not navigationController , you should start from y = 44,, ScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)];

Comment: Oh, this is very good. That is working. Thanks you so much. You save my development time. I really thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mined the hierarchy of the view , if the UIScrollView is on top of the views , then any view behinde it will not receive any touch event.
The navigation bar added with XIB is a part of the subviews in you main view so you have to start the UIScrollView under the navigation bar , y = 44

```
ScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height-44)];
```

and do not forget to subtract 44 from the ScrollView height to fit the screen.

Comment: Thanks for your guide line. Your answer is very useful for my development. I appreciate your help. Thanks again Aziz.